# ¿Como enviar un parámetro con distintos valores de filas en una tabla al controlador?

Tags: c#, mvc

junto con saludar, resulta que tengo un problema, tengo un boton el cual llamo a una ventana modal mediante un parametro (serieDesplegar) que se compara a una fila de la misma tabla (rme_codigo), pero solo me toma el primer valor de la fila y me los repite hacia abajo, hay posibilidad de poder abrir una ventana modal por cada valor de cada fila? adjunto mi codigo y unas fotos.

```
  <div class="card mb-3">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
                                Listado DATACARD
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Tablas", "Dashboard", FormMethod.Get))
                                    {
                                        <p>
                                            <div style="text-align:initial;" />
                                            Busqueda por codigo: @Html.TextBox("rme_codigo")
                                            <input type="submit" value="Filtro de busqueda" button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" />
                                        </p>
                                    }
                                </div>


                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table class="table table-bordered" style="table-layout:fixed" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>CODIGO</th>
                                                <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
                                                <th>DETALLE EMBOSADORA</th>
                                                <th>LOG MAQUINA</th>
                                                <th>VIGENCIA</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>CODIGO</th>
                                                <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
                                                <th>DETALLE EMBOSADORA</th>
                                                <th>LOG MAQUINA</th>
                                                <th>VIGENCIA</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tfoot>



                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                                {
                                                    var color = "#fff";
                                                    if (item.rme_vigente == false)
                                                    {
                                                        color = "#DC3546";
                                                    }
                                                    else if (item.rme_vigente == true)
                                                    {
                                                        color = "#27A844";
                                                    }

                                            <tr>

                                                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: left;">
                                                        @item.rme_codigo
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: left;">
                                                        @item.rme_descripcion
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn-info" style="width:100px; text-align: center">Detalles</button>
                                                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-url="@Url.Action("partialViewPrueba", "Date", new { serieDesplegar = item.rme_codigo })">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;">

                                                        @Html.ActionLink("Descargar log", "TraerLog", "Dashboard", new { @class = "btn" })
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="width: 1%; text-align: center;">
                                                        @Html.Action("verStatuss", "Dashboard", new { serieDesplegar = item.rme_codigo})
                                                    </td>

                                            </tr>

                                                }
                                            </tbody>

                                        </table>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated yesterday at 11:59 PM</div>
                            </div>
```

Desde mi controlador llamo a la clase que obtengo los datos:

```
    public ActionResult partialViewPrueba(string serieDesplegar)//get
    {
        string[] holiweb = new string[6];
        holiweb = logica.desplegarTabla(serieDesplegar);
        ViewBag.viubag1 = holiweb;
        return PartialView(logica.desplegarTabla(serieDesplegar));
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult partialViewPrueba(Embozadora embo)//post
    {
        return View();
    }
```

mi pagina se ve asi: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo le di click al detalle de la fila donde esta el codigo (DatacardSD260M1), pero siempre me aparece el primer codigo de la fila( EvolisPrimacy4), no me muestra ninguno mas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ventana modal:

```
                @if (ViewBag.viubag1 != null)
            {
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>N° Serie</td>
                            <td>Sucursal</td>
                            <td>Status</td>
                            <td>Cantidad Incidencias</td>
                            <td>Fecha Activa</td>
                            <td>Tarjeta</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @ViewBag.viubag1[0]
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @ViewBag.viubag1[1]
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @ViewBag.viubag1[2]
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @ViewBag.viubag1[3]
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @ViewBag.viubag1[4]
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @ViewBag.viubag1[5]
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                    </table>
                </div>}
```

Lo que deseo es dar clic en detalles y muestre un modal con los detalles de la embosadora seleccionada, espero se entienda, quedo antento a una ayuda!

Comment: Lo que deseas es que al dar clic en detalles te muestre un modal con los detalles de la embosadora seleccionada?

Comment: Eso mismo @VicenteAlmea

Comment: Depuraste que es lo que trae el parámetro en tu método **partialViewPrueba**?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera, lo que hace es enviar la serieDesplegar con el mismo CODIGO de la tabla a la clase desplegarTabla, que esta conectado a un ws, si no se envia un codigo a la clase desplegarTabla, no inicia y manda error, ya que debe tener un codigo para iniciar el proceso

Comment: Si puedes agrega el codigo donde levantas el modal, debes tener algo de javascript para trabajar con el modal

Comment: @VicenteAlmea Asi estuve leyendo algo, vere si puedo concretarlo, gracias ..

Comment: @VicenteAlmea, ahi lo agregue

Answer (score 1):

Me he tropezado con muchos casos en que deseo el mismo resultado que tu, los he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

le agrego una clase al botón de detalles y como id el Id del item(prefiero pasarle el Id y no el irm_codigo ), te quedaría de esta forma

```
 <button type="button" id="@item.Id" class="btn-info detalles" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="width:100px; text-align: center">Detalles</button>
```

Al final de tu vista agregas un modal vacío, el cual llenarás con js, Esta forma es mucho más óptima ya que estamos reutilizando un solo modal para mostrar el contenido y del otro modo estás declarando un modal por cada item de tu foreach:

```
         <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title center">Detalles Embosadora</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="modalDetalles">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Si te das cuenta en la estructura del modal podemos dejar el modal-header , modal-title y modal-footer ya que son el mismo para cada vista, no varian y pueden ser reutilizados, todos los modal van a tener como título "Detalles de Embosadora", por lo que todo se queda = menos el `<div id="modalDetalles"></div>`, aquí es que queremos los detalles de cada Embosadora, lo que sería el modal-body el que varía.

luego agregamos algo de javascript para poder llenar el modal-body con los datos al darle clicl al botón.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {    
          $('.detalles').on("click", function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var url = "@Url.Action("partialViewPrueba", "Embosadora")/" + id;
                $("#modalDetalles").load(url);                
           });  
       });
<script>
```

de esta forma al dar click en detalles se levanta el modal por `data-target` y se ejecuta la función que conforma una url y la renderiza dentro del div con id modalDetalles

Asumiendo que tienes un controlador llamado EmbosadoraController y una acción llamada partialViewPrueba:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult partialViewPrueba(int? id)
    {
        var embosadora = db.Embosadoras.Find(id);//esto es una consulta la cual retorna una Embosadora fialtarda por un Id, no se como seria en tu caso.
        return PartialView("_DetallesEmbosadoraPartial", embosadora);
    }
```

solo te faltaría agregar en la vista aprcial, el modelo del cual depende y todo el contenido que quieras dentro de modal-body. ejemplo

en la vista _DetallesEmbosadoraPartial.cshtml agregamos:

`@model MiProyecto.Models.Embosadora`    //definimos un modelo ya que le pasamos una embosadora desde el controlador

```
 <div class="modal-body">

//Aqui dentro muestras los detalles como quieras

</div>
```

de esta forma toda esta aprtial que contiene los detalles de tu embosadora se va a cargar en el `div` con id `modalDetalles` de tu modal mediante `$("#modalDetalles").load(url);` puede que te cueste un poco entender esto pero espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Muchas gracias vicente, te cuento como me va, probare hoy

Comment: Una consulta, en que lado del codigo javascript me toma el valor de rme_codigo ??

Comment: en ninguna parte, recuerda que sustituí el rme_codigo por el id del item,

Comment: Gracias, no se casi nada de JS, al final agregue una variable de boton y la implemente en el codigo del modal, ahi entro, gracias!!